# Has anybody ever tried to screen scrape data from sites built with SharePoint?

Tags: sharepoint, screen-scraping

Or at least could anybody point me to docs about its crazy proprietary url parameters and html field name obfuscation? I can only suppose this is caused by SharePoint...

The main problem is, given a start page built with SharePoint, I can't recreate a form post with a programmative client because:

- field names vary, they are appended with a some sort of id, hash, whatever (I think session.wise? Not sure)
- tracing HTTP traffic on my side, I see the HTTP request is packed with strange parameters like `__REQUESTDIGEST`, `__VIEWSTATE`, and many others

Is this an intentional protection device put up by SharePoint? Which is the underlying architecture and which objects are involved (script callbacks, ... )?

(BTW, I'm not doing anything evil, just trying to extract **public government data** from a website).

Thanks.

Comment: Hi. I'm currently looking at scraping a SharePoint site and wondering if you got anywhere with this?

Comment: Sorry, I left that site alone after all

Comment: Okay, thanks. I'm struggling with a similar issue!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SharePoint is nothing more than an ASP.NET Application, SharePoint completely Built on top of ASP.NET 2.0.
Being said that **__VIEWSTATE** is nothing but a Hidden Field that has the [View State](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972976.aspx) Information

Coming to **__REQUESTDIGEST** this is an Intentional Protection, this carries some sort of 
securito validation which is called [FormDigest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.webcontrols.formdigest.aspx)

And finally to answer your Question, You will not be able to guess field and stuffs unless you have control to change the sourcecode of the application. Reason why the Name of the fields  looks like obfuscated is because those controls are not handwritten but generated by the Code of ASP.NET Engine and parser, Reason field having such a name  called [Naming Container](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.namingcontainer.aspx)

One suggestion I would say is that, rather than trying to scraping the screen data, you can try alternate approaches, like each of the List in the SharePoint has the XML Feed inbuilt,try to consume it, if you have access to the site, try to retrieve the information using export to excel etc.

Comment: Unfortunately I've no access to the site.
Thank you very much for the explanation.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to RSS, SharePoint also has a Web Services interface that you can use to get at and interact with data stored in SharePoint in a programatic way.